# Spring Boot - How to track all requests and responses with exceptions and save into database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two micro services(Spring Boot) for integration between two Product.My architecture is like below.

Product1 <-------> microservice1/microservice2 <------> Product1.

My task is I need to track requests with input prams (with methods, eg. GET, POST, etc), request path, query string, corresponding class method of this request, also response of this action, both success and errors and save into database table.
 I have tried spring boot actuator. But no luck.
 Please suggest how to achieve that.

Comment: use Zuul API to catch all request and response

Comment: I am using spring boot

Comment: Use zipkin for that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `HandlerInterceptor` that you can register to the two micro-services REST controllers. It has a nice lifecycle call-backs that you can use to serialize the data and save it into the database. Here's the custom interceptor class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class DBRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         Object handler) throws Exception {

        // DB logic

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

        // DB logic

        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }
}
```

Once you had developed this re-usable handler, you can register in the web configurer. Here's the code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Autowired
   private DBRequestInterceptor interceptor;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
       registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns("/**/");
   }
}
```

This code registers the interceptor on all of your URL mappings. You can customize it to some specific services URLs.

You might find an exception in the original code once you read the request stream in the above interceptor. In that case, you can leverage the Spring wrapper classes `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you have any github link.It will be useful.

Comment: How to save the Payload?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an exact GitHub link for the above code. But you can read the body using the InputStream method of the `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`. Here's a sample code of the `preHandle` method

    
        HttpServletRequest requestWrapper
                = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        requestWrapper.getParameterMap();
        requestWrapper.getInputStream();
        //read the stream

Comment: There is also another interceptor that can get you the body contents directly without the need to use the wrapper. Here is a sample implementation of it: 

https://gist.github.com/jkuipers/24ffbf8a5ba26c0177629e9aba492bfa